# Oracle kerberos authentication service canonicalization

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, kerberos

I have a nodejs application using kerberos to authenticate to two separate services. One is an Oracle database & the second is an HTTP api. When connecting to each of these services independently, kerberos authentication is successful.

The problem comes when attempting to connect to both in a single process. The web API's service name is a load balanced CNAME. Once the database connection is set up, all subsequent kerberos requests for tickets use DNS canonicalization *on the clientside* prior to negotiating a ticket for any service, despite setting rdns=false in the kerberos configuration.

```
[libdefaults] 
rdns=false
```

This causes all attempts to access the web api to fail.

```
Error: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information: Server not found in Kerberos database
```

I am explicitly pointing oracle (via sqlnet.ora) to use the kerberos configuration containing the above libdefaults section. I'm a little lost on what to consider next, does anyone know if its possible to tell oracle to not do DNS canonicalization for kerberos auth?

Comment: On the slim chance that Kerberos behavior changed due to some of the work in the 21c client to support multiple wallets in a single client process, you could try using that version of the client libraries.  Otherwise, contact Oracle Support and ask how an Oracle Call Interface app would handle your scenario.